# .txt file does not print after being written with a join lines command in python

Tags: python, printing, line, text-files

I'm new to Python and I have the following question:

I am writing the first 72 lines of a .txt-file to another .txt-file, textA.txt.

```
textA = open('textA.txt', 'w')
textA.write('\n'.join(lines[1:72]))
textA.close
```

Now, as I intended, the textA file contains 72 sentences, each starting at a new line.
However, when I do a line count or I am trying to print the file through

```
f=open ('textA.txt','r')
print f.read()
```

nothing happens (and the nonblank lines count is zero).

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What is `lines` in your first snippet?

Comment: `textA.close()`, you missed the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you haven't closed the file handle, and the `write` may not have finished.  `close` function needs to be called :: `textA.close()`.

To not have to worry about remembering to close files, use the `with` statement.

```
with open('textA.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(lines[1:72]))
```

And then, read back your file, as required

```
with open('textA.txt') as f:
    print f.readlines()
```